# Найти элементы в списке, разница между которыми равна единице

Tags: python, массивы

Даётся массив из 7 элементов, отсортированный по убыванию (от большего к меньшему)
Найти элементы в списке, разница между которыми равна единице в количестве пяти штук подряд. Например 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 2, 1 - Победа. 
Помогите написать код.

Код, который работает неправильно:

```
import random

n = 0

array1 = []
array2 = []

while True:

    array1.clear()
    array2.clear()

    for i in range(13):

        array1.append(i)

    random.shuffle(array1)

    for i in array1:

        if i < 7:
            array2.append(array1[i])

    array2.sort()
    array2.reverse()

    for i in array2:

        if i < len(array2):
            a = array2[i] - 1

            if i + 1 < len(array2): 
                b = array2[i + 1]

                if a == b:
                    n = n + 1

                else:
                    n = 0
    if n == 5:
        print(array2)
        print("Victory!")
        break
```

Переделал код, но не понимаю, почему не работает.

```
import random

r = 13
rc = 0
index = 0
victory = 0


array1 = []
array2 = []

while True:
    array1.clear()
    array2.clear()
    for i in range(13):
        array1.append(i)

    random.shuffle(array1)

    for i in array1:
        if i < 7:
            array2.append(array1[i])

    array2.sort()
    array2.reverse()

    while True:

        for i in array2:
            if i < len(array2):
                x = r - array2[i]
                if x == 1:
                    rc = rc + 1
                    r = r - 1
                    if rc >= 5:
                        victory = 1
                        break
                else:
                    rc = 0

        if victory == 1:
            print(array2)
            print("Victory!")
            break

        r = 13
        index = index + 1
        r = r - index

        if r > 4:
            for i in array2:
                if i < len(array2):
                    x = r - array2[i]
                    if x == 1:
                        rc = rc + 1
                        r = r - 1
                        if rc >= 5:
                            victory = 1
                            break
                    else:
                        rc = 0


        if victory == 1:
            print(array2)
            print("Victory!")
            break
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Нужен код. Мой работает неправильно.

Comment: Так, вы пишите, что array2 должен содержать именно те значения array1, которые меньше 7. Обновите пример. Кстати, именно здесь может быть ошибка

Comment: Да, ошибка определенно здесь. Потому что шанс того, что они расположатся по возрастанию  или по убыванию равен 1/840

Comment: Если даже поместить 7 рандомных значений из array1, то шанс будет 1/252. Уточните условия задания, мне не верится, что оно таково.

Comment: Задание: Нужно найти пять чисел по порядку (подряд) с соотношением -1 из  массива с семью элементами. Например: 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 2, 1 или 12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5.
Я сделал массив и заполнил его, перемешал, сделал второй массив из 7 элементов, хотя можно было бы и напрямую. Потому начал кумекать, но ничего пока не получилось дельного.

Comment: Miron, я добавляю в массив array2 первые 7 элементов array1. Потом сортирую array2 по убыванию. И получаю массив со случайными числами. Тут всё правильно.

Comment: Извините, не знаю питон. Но, если это так, как вы сказали, я уверен, что можно построить for более элегантно(вроде, у вас есть какой-то in range(), не знаю). Но вероятность такого исхода(когда вы победите) все равно крайне мала.

Comment: нет, неправда. i принимает значение массива(пруф - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp).

Comment: Спасибо. Я нашел решение. Напишу позже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно разок пройтись и проверить разности, храня позицию начала хорошей серии

```
def fivedec(a):
    start = 0
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if (a[i-1] - a[i] != 1):
            start = i
        elif (i-start == 4):
            return True
    return False

print(fivedec([13,12, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант решения задачи (отладочные блоки и строки надо убрать).

```
import random
l=1
j1=0
j2=0
j3=0
j4=0
j5=0

victory = 0
bool = True

array1 = []
array2 = []

while bool:
    bool1 = False
    bool2 = False
    bool3 = False
    bool4 = False
    bool5 = False
    k=0
    array1.clear()
    array2.clear()
    for i in range(13):
        array1.append(int(i))

    random.shuffle(array1)
    for i in array1:
        if i < 7:
            array2.append(array1[i])
    array2.sort()
    array2.reverse()

    l=l+1    # общий счетчик количества итераций в цикле
    for k in range(0,2):      # просмотр двух возможных вариантов
        bool1 = ((array2[0+k]-array2[1+k])==1)
        bool2 = ((array2[1+k]-array2[2+k])==1)
        bool3 = ((array2[2+k]-array2[3+k])==1)
        bool4 = ((array2[3+k]-array2[4+k])==1)
        bool5 = ((array2[4+k]-array2[5+k])==1)

        if bool1:     # статистика для отладки
            j1=j1+1
        if bool1 and bool2:
            j2=j2+1
        if bool1 and bool2 and bool3:
            j3=j3+1
        if bool1 and bool2 and bool3 and bool4:
            j4=j4+1   # конец стат.блока для отладки
        if bool1 and bool2 and bool3 and bool4 and bool5:
            j5=j5+1
            victory = 1
            if victory == 1:
                print(array1)  # Отладочный блок из 3-х строк
                print(array2)  #
                print("Кол.попыток=",l, " 1п= ",j1," 2п=",j2," 3п=",j3," 4п=",j4," Victory= ",j5)
                print("Victory!")
                bool = False
```